# Understand declaration of a terminal operation method

Tags: methods, declaration, return-type, collectors

Usually, a method's declaration shows its return type, method full path, and parameters. But when I look at method `java.util.stream.Stream.collect` I am confused.

It seems that the method has **two** return types:

```
<List<Integer>, Object> List<Integer> java.util.stream.Stream.collect(Collector<? super Integer, Object, List<Integer>> collector)
```

I understand that its *real* return type is `List<Integer>`, but what does `<List<Integer>, Object>` mean? Why is it one space before `List<Integer>` and why is its key(if it is a map?) the same as the real return type?

Comment: The first thing is not a return type, it specifies types for the generic type parameters R and A. Reading javadoc could help here. The method returns R, so the return type has to be the same as the type parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the declaration of the method:

```
public interface Stream<T> extends BaseStream<T, Stream<T>> {
    ...
    /* ...
     * @param <R> the type of the result
     * @param <A> the intermediate accumulation type of the {@code Collector}
     * ...
     */
    <R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
    ...
}
```

As Nathan pointed out in the comments, the `<R, A>` denotes generic type parameters. These will be inferred by the Java compiler as long as it is unambiguous. In your case `R` was inferred to `List<Integer>` and `A` to `Object`. You can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) about generic methods.

Comment: Reading from these links https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html after the answer, I understand now.